# PL/pgSQL perform vs execute

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

What are the difference between perform and execute on PL/pgSQL?

From the manual:

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but discard the result, for example when calling a function that has side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use the PERFORM statement.

But, when I'm trying something like:

```
perform 'create table foo as (select 1)';
```

Nothing happens. Although this query should have side effects (creating table), and the result can be discarded.

I think I get 1 thing right: in order to run functions I can use perform:

```
perform pg_temp.addInheritance(foo);
```

Comment: `perform` replaces `select`. it is select ignoring the return, you can't `select 'create table foo as (select 1)';`

Comment: In other words, it cannot make any change to the database?

Comment: it can, same way `select` can. no more no less. Eg `select pg_create_restore_point('change to db');` or select 1 from dblink_exec('local', 'create table...') as (i int)` or so

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`PERFORM` is plpgsql command used for calls of void functions. PLpgSQL is careful about useless  `SELECT` statements - the `SELECT` without `INTO` clause is not allowed. But sometimes you need to call a function and you don't need to store result (or functions has no  result). The function in `SQL` is called with `SELECT` statement. But it is not possible in PLpgSQL - so the command `PERFORM` was introduced.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Hello from void function';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- direct call from SQL
SELECT foo();

-- in PLpgSQL
DO $$
BEGIN
  SELECT foo(); -- is not allowed
  PERFORM foo(); -- is ok
END;
$$;
```

The `PERFORM` statements execute a parameter and forgot result.

Your example `perform 'create table foo as (select 1)';`

is same like `SELECT 'create table foo as (select 1)'`. It returns a string "create table foo as (select 1)" and this string is discarded.

The `EXECUTE` statement evaluate a expression to get string. In next step this string is executed.

So `EXECUTE 'create table ' || some_var || '(a int)';` has two steps

1. evaluate expression `'create table ' || some_var || '(a int)'`
2. if `some_var` is mytab for example, then execute a command `create table mytab(a int)`

The `PERFORM` statement is used for function calls, when functions are not used in assignment statement. The `EXECUTE` is used for evaluation of dynamic SQL - when a form of SQL command is known in runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Further next line in [docs you quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

> This executes query and discards the result. **Write the query the same
>   way you would write an SQL SELECT command**, but replace the initial
>   keyword SELECT with PERFORM.

Emphasis mine

`execute` in its turn executes dynamic query (same docs above)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a case where I needed to set specific constraints to DEFERRED and found something interesting.

```
 - EXECUTE 'SET CONSTRAINTS fk_a DEFERRED';
 - PERFORM 'SET CONSTRAINTS fk_a DEFERRED';
```

Both `EXECUTE` and `PERFORM` executed the statements without error but only EXECUTE persisted the action for the rest of the code.
Somehow, it looks like PERFORM runs in it's own transaction `"bubble"`.

In my case I had two tables a and b and a FK (the real stuation is much more complex). There was a need to insert the data out of the parent/child order and for that we needed the constraint `DEFERRED`.
Using the `PERFORM` we had a foreign key violation, with `EXECUTE` we didn't.

Comment: Did you ever learn anything more about this? I'm not facing this problem, nor anything similar, but it seems mightly interesting