# Execute PSQL procedure for multiple records matching criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to run a procedure manually for a large set of records that meet a certain criteria. It works fine if I manually include an ID but for some reason it does not work if I just tell it to get a list of ids from a table. No errors; but the missing data doesn't get added to a table from the procedure.

As far as I understand it, this should work fine but it doesn't:

```
select fa_sptl_cross(id, geom) from focus_area where generation_id = 3;
```

But this works fine

```
select fa_sptl_cross(id, geom) from focus_area where id = 312231;
```

Even this should work, should it not?

```
select fa_sptl_cross(id, geom) from focus_area
```

Ideas?

AFAIK, it cannot be the procedure that is the issue because trying to do this fails with *any* procedure I try

Comment: Currently trying the selected answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920998/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-execute . Been running for 30 minutes so I'm hoping it's actually working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the information provided in [PL/pgSQL perform vs execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920998/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-execute)

My solution is as follows:

```
DO $$
    BEGIN
      PERFORM habits4.fav_sptl_cross(focus_area_id, geom) from habits4.focus_area_version where generation_id = 3;
    END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please explain to me what does this function (`fa_sptl_cross`) does? If you can write the source code of this function that I could analyze this.

In general, I understand that when you are using `where id = 312231` your query returns one record, that's why your function works fine. Because your function has an input parameter `id`. In other ways query return, many records, many id's, so and your function doesn't work. So I must view the source code of this function. I think so.